# JPA entities cannot create the correct db tables

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, glassfish

we are having a slight issue with our application

we are trying to get a login page set up and run with glassfish so that can do the authentication, in our test application we could do this but we used tables :

```
   create table person(
            username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT USER_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
            password varchar(128) NOT NULL
..... many more fields here but are just for dob etc
    );
```

and

```
create table usergroup(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupname varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupname),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES person(username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );
```

this worked well but for this application we are trying to get the entities to manage everything and create the tables, the issue we are having is with the `constraints` we set up, how can we set this up in the entites ?

The person entities

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany
    private List<UserGroup> userGroupList;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName, surname, username, password, telephoneNumber, emailAddress,gender;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date DateOfBirth;
    public Person() {
    }

           public void addToGroups(UserGroup ug) {
        this.userGroupList.add(ug);
    }
```

and the usergroup entity

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person person;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username, groupName;
```

we need the constraints and settings as with out these are we not able to authenticate correctly using glassfish

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error message?